# python3: how do i ask a user for input to select a specific list, (yes or no) and then print the items in that specific list in a random order?

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops, random, input

python3: how do i ask a user for input to select a specific list, and then print the items in that specific list in a random order? and then repeat the program to ask the user if which list they would like to select

```
    #lists of healthy food
    Fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears']
    Vegies = ['carrots', 'tomatoes', 'broccoli']

    #lists of meats
    Red_meat = ['steak', 'hamburgers']
    White_meat = ['chicken', 'turkey']


    import random
```

the code i have below just looks repetitive and annoying. there must be an easier way to print this as a string of text

****i would like to have the user asked for input  (which list would you like 
    to select from?****

```
    #Healthy foods #
    #then print out something along the lines of
    OUTPUT: oranges, tomatoes, pears, carrots

    print(random.choice(Fruits), end= " ")
    print(random.choice(Vegies), end= " ")
    print(random.choice(Fruits), end= " ")
    print(random.choice(Vegies), end= " ")
```

then ask the user if it would like to run the same list again, or select a 
            different list

```
    #would you like to run this same list(yes or no)
    if yes: (runs again)
    if no: (Which list would you like to run?)

    lists of meats:
    print(random.choice(Red_meat), end= " ")
    print(random.choice(White_meat), end= " ")
    print(random.choice(Red_meat), end= " ")
    print(random.choice(White_meat), end= " ")

   OUTPUT: steak, turkey, hamburgers, chicken
again?
   OUTPUT: hamburgers, chicken, steak, chicken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does very non-bulletproof user input. It's suitable for a demo program but not for the real world.

To have a single `print` call you need to build up a list of the data you want the user to see. I've given you a sample but there are lots of ways to do it.

The loop in `display_list` may look a bit daunting but it is like that to make it easy to add new categories to `Healthy_food` and `Meats`. Your code has the fact that there are only 2 categories of each hard-coded into it.

```
import random

Healthy_food = dict(
    #lists of healthy food
    Fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears'],
    Vegies = ['carrots', 'tomatoes', 'broccoli'],
    )
Meats =  dict(
    Red_meat = ['steak', 'hamburgers'],
    White_meat = ['chicken', 'turkey'],
    )

All_food = {
    1: Meats,
    0: Healthy_food,
    }

def display_list(choice): # choice can be 0: Healthy_food or 1: Meats
    selection = []
    for i in range(2): # gives 2 random choices from each category
      for options in All_food[choice].values():
        selection.append(random.choice(options))
    print (' '.join(selection))

def interact():
    response = input('Do you want a list of Meats or Healthy food, or Quit? ').lower()
    while 'q' not in response and response != '':
        while True:
            display_list('meat' in response)
            if 'y' not in input('Again? ').lower():
                break
        response = input('Do you want a list of Meats or Healthy food, or Quit? ').lower()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    interact()
```

Comment: BoarGules THANK YOU, this really made me see what needed to be done, perfectly. the healthy/meats were an example, im doing something thats a little more theoretical and scenario based. I understand what you mean by the real world application though